# Filter observable value

Tags: angular, typescript, reactive-programming

I have a simple function that call's my firebase database to get a list of items. I'm looking for a simple way of filtering these items by location.liked === true. However, I haven't been able to accomplish this using the traditional filter array method. Do any of you have a sense of how this could be done?

```
this.locations = af.database.list('/trips')
  .map((locations) => {
    return locations.map((location) => {
      location.liked = af.database.object(`/likes/${this.uid}/${location.$key}`);
      return location;
    })
  });
```

My initial approach has been to use the following logic

```
this.filteredResult = locations.map((locations) => {
 return locations.filter((location) => {
  return location.liked
 })
})
```

However, this gives me the error that any[] cannot be filtered

Comment: how does your function containing this code look like?

Comment: It's actually the full function above placed in the constructor for my class. It's worth nothing that I have defined locations in the class as locations: Observable<any[]>;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
this.locations = af.database.list('/trips').filter((location) => {
    return location.liked === true;
});
```

Check this example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/U9p7LHFsYIXeFiJkIiRs?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That returns the following error: Property 'liked' does not exist on type 'any[]'. I think the reason might be that af.database.list returns an observable

Comment: @user3642173 în that case just change the code to af.database.list('/trips').map(locations => locations.filter((location) => {  return location.liked === true;}))

Comment: Thanks Luis. This is what I initially tried but it returns the same error. Can it have to so.with the result from location.liked also being an observable?